# How implement a lookup utility class with an array member variable?

Tags: c++, c++20

[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759b26925a535d70)

I need to implement a utility class for the purpose of lookup. The value of the internal array never changes after the initialization. My initial plan was to implement this class with the help of `constexpr` so that the expensive initialization can be done in compilation time. However, I am not able to come up with a good solution. So far, I can only figure out the following two methods. Both methods have drawbacks.

**Method One**:
The implementation looks complicate for such a simple task.

**Method Two**:

First, I assume the initialization is done in compilation time. Is this correct?

Second, the `TwoClass::m_array` really should be static instead of a member variable.

Is there a better way to implement this with `c++20`?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//== Method One
class OneClass
{
public:
    uint32_t get(size_t index)
    {
        return m_array[index % 0xFF];
    }

    struct init_static_array
    {
        init_static_array()
        {
            // std::cout << "call init_static_array\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                m_array[i] = i * i + 10;
            }
        }
    };
    
private:
    static init_static_array m_init_static_array;
    enum {N = 255};
    static int m_array[N]; // this is a lookup table and NEVER will be changed!
};

int OneClass::m_array[] = {0};
OneClass::init_static_array OneClass::m_init_static_array{};

//== Method Two
class TwoClass
{
public:
    constexpr TwoClass()
    {
        //std::cout << "call TwoClass::TwoClass()\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            m_array[i] = i * i + 10;
        }
    }
    
    int get(size_t index) const
    {
        return m_array[index % 0xFF];
    }
    
private:
    enum {N = 255};
    int m_array[N] {0}; // this is a lookup table and NEVER will be changed!
};

int main()
{
    OneClass oneclass;
    cout << "1 => " << oneclass.get(1) << std::endl;
    cout << "256 => " << oneclass.get(256) << std::endl;
    
    cout << "==================\n";
    
    TwoClass twoclass;
    cout << "1 => " << twoclass.get(1) << std::endl;
    cout << "256 => " << twoclass.get(256) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
call init_static_array
1 => 11
256 => 11
==================
call TwoClass::TwoClass()
1 => 11
256 => 11
```

Comment: Applying `constexpr` to `TwoClass::TwoClass` you lie to the user: in no context is this constructor able to be evaluated at compile time, because of `std::cout << ...;`; As for `enum {N = 255};`: Do you intend the readers to scratch their heads? Just replace this with `static constexpr size_t N = 255;`. Furthermore to get a real benefit here, you should make the `get` function `constexpr` too.

Comment: Note: For members other than the constructor you may want to take a look at [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to see where `constexpr` could be applied...

Comment: @fabian, I should have removed that `std::cout`. Sorry, it was there for debug purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

If it's C++20, don't you just want this:

```cpp
namespace {
constexpr std::size_t N{255u};
consteval std::array<int, N> initArr()
{
    std::array<int, N> arr{};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = i * i + 10;
    }
    return arr;
}
}
class C
{
private:
    constexpr static std::array<int, N> arr{initArr()};
public:
    constexpr C() = default;
    int get(std::size_t n) const {return arr[n%255];}
};
```

Comment: In the OP, I need this array to be within a class since it is unrelated to others.

Comment: But you have also mentioned that "Second, the TwoClass::m_array really should be static instead of a member variable."

Comment: The size if off by 1 compared to the question. Furthermore `std::array` is lacking the functionality of taking the remainder of the division of the index passed divided by the size...

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your methods initialized the array at compile-time.

In the first method, the array is initialized in construction of static data member `m_init_static_array`, e.g. before `main` is called.

In the second method, `constexpr` in function declarations, including constructors, indicates that you want them being able to be called at compile-time, e.g. in evaluation of constant expressions. It doesn't mean all invocations are evaluated at compile-time. To call constexpr functions as compile-time, you have to call them in constant expression.

One solution is to initialize the static constexpr data member `internal_array` of type `std::array` by a lambda:

```cpp
#include <array>

class Demo {
public:
    int get(int index) const {
      return internal_array[index % N];
    }

private:
    static inline constexpr int N = 255;

    static inline constexpr std::array<int, N> internal_array = []() {
        // Cannot call non-constexpr functions at compile-time
        // std::cout << "std::cout << "call init_static_array\n";

        std::array<int, N> arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            arr[i] = i * i + 10;
        return arr;
    }();
};

int main() {
  Demo demo;
  return demo.get(10);
}
```